# Prisma schema unique

Tags: database, prisma

I want  the user to have many addresses
address belongs to one user
and that's what i presented here
But ..

- I want the user to have only one address that (isDefault = true)
- And unlimited addresses that isDefault = false

how do i do that

here is my prisma schema

```
model User {
  id          String   @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  name        String
  email       String   @unique
  password    String
  phoneNumber String?  @db.VarChar(50)
  isActive    Boolean  @default(false)
  isAdmin     Boolean  @default(false)
  resetCode   String?  @unique
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt

  addresses Address[]

  @@index([email])
}

model Address {
  id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  addressLine1 String
  addressLine2 String?
  phoneNumber  String
  addressName  String
  email        String
  country      String
  state        String
  name         String
  postalCode   String
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt

  userId String @db.Uuid
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema design allows a user to have multiple addresses, but it doesn't enforce the constraint that only one of these addresses can have isDefault = true. To enforce this rule, you would need to do it at the application level in your code logic, since Prisma and most SQL databases do not provide a built-in way to enforce this kind of constraint.

You'll need to add the `isDefault` field to your `Address` model.

Your schema could look something like this:

```
model Address {
  id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  addressLine1 String
  addressLine2 String?
  phoneNumber  String
  addressName  String
  email        String
  country      String
  state        String
  name         String
  postalCode   String
  isDefault    Boolean  @default(false)
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt

  userId String @db.Uuid
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}
```

Then in your application code, whenever an address is set as the default, you would need to ensure that all other addresses for that user are not the default.

You can do something like this to enforce that:

```js
async function setDefaultAddress(userId: string, addressId: int) {
  // Begin a transaction
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()
  const trans = await prisma.$transaction([
    prisma.address.updateMany({
      where: {
        userId: userId,
        isDefault: true,
      },
      data: {
        isDefault: false,
      },
    }),
    prisma.address.update({
      where: { id: addressId },
      data: { isDefault: true },
    }),
  ])
}
```

Comment: I tried to use defaultAddressId in the User model but that doesn't satisfy the prisma type checking